# Ado.net connection to mysql in ssis

Tags: mysql, ssis

I have 60 table in my sql in 60 different servers from 192.168.69.1 to 192.168.69.60

When I create a single mysql connection and read data from first table its worked.

But when I create a parameterized connection with expression, it's not working and I see this error :

> [ADO NET Source [2]] Error: An error occurred executing the provided SQL command: "select * from mdl_adobeconnect". SELECT command denied to user 'biteam'@'192.168.12.20' for table 'mdl_adobeconnect'

But I have full permission on all tables.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue.  Are you running it locally or from the server?  Maybe the server account that is running the job does not have permissions.

Comment: Can you show how you have parameterized the connection? Connection Manager, Properties, Expressions... and then show the Expressions you have used and the Property they are controlling.

Comment: hi tnx
1- I created an ado.net resource 
2- click new for connection
3- new again and choose MySQL DataProvider(i installed MySqlConnector)
4- i set server(192.168.2.1) database (X) and user and pass and test connectin is succes
5- right clik on connection in connection manager select parameterize
6- in property select server name andf click ok

Comment: 7- i go in Connection properties and select Expresion and server name from parameters 'ServerByMe' that this is valued from for loop Because i want to read this table (Y) from 192.168.2.1 to 192.168.2.60.

These steps work for a series of tables, but they do not work for a series of tables and i see error:
(Error: 0xC020838F at Data Flow Task_Users, ADO NET Source [2]: An error occurred executing the provided SQL command: "select 
*

 from mdl_adobeconnect". SELECT command denied to user 'biteam'@'192.168.12.20' for table 'mdl_adobeconnect'
) 192.168.12.20 is mine